# Cannot import a module from a package

Tags: python

```
root_package
|---main_package
|    |--__init__.py
|    |--main.py 
|---write_to_file
|    |--__init__.py
|    |--write.py  
|
|---__init__.py
```

I'm tryin to access a function that's in main.py from write.py like this:

**write.py**

```
from root_package.main_package.main import getProduct
```

and I get the following **error: No module named 'root_package'**

I know this is basic and most asked question, but I can't find the answer from other posts. I'm just not seeing what is wrong. Thanks

EDIT:
I'm trying to run write.py script like this:

root_package\write_to_file\write.py python write.py

Comment: Where are you running your `main.py` script from? If from `root_package` directory, try `from main_package.main import getProduct`.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych oh, I forgot to add that. I'm actually trying to run write.py script. Naming isn't the best, but yeah..

Comment: So you run it from `write_to_file` directory? Try using `from main_package.main import getProduct` and run it from `root_package` with `python write_to_file/write.py`

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Yes, but now I'm getting "no module named 'main_package' " :/